# Convert String[] with text to double[]

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist, double

I have an Arraylist that I want to convert to a double[] array. I first convert the Arraylist to a String []. I then try to convert the String[] to a double[] but fail in the process. Here's the issue: the string contains some text, as well as some numbers with decimals. I want to convert only the numbers and decimals to a double[] array and simply delete the text. However, I only know how to delete the text with a String, not a String[]. Please take a look:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import jsc.independentsamples.SmirnovTest;

public class example {
    public static void main(String[] arg) throws Exception {
        ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();

        list1.add("RSP0001,1.11,1.22");
        list1.add("RSP0002,2.11,2.22");
        list1.add("RSP0003,3.11,3.22");
        list1.add("RSP0004,4.11,4.22");

        String[] str1 = new String[list1.size()];
        str1 = list1.toArray(str1);
        str1.replaceAll("RSP_\\d+","");
        double array1 = Double.parseDouble(str1);

        System.out.println(array1);
    }
}
```

Two errors come from this: the first is a "cannot find symbol" error at str1.replaceAll. The second is a "method parseDouble" error at "Double.parseDouble". The issue there is I need a String instead of a String[].

Any ideas on how to convert my String[] to a double[] ?

Thanks,

kjm

Comment: If this is java code, you should probably use the [tag:java] tag.

Comment: Also, is there any reason why you're creating an `ArrayList<String>` then converting to `String[]` immediately, instead of just creating a `String[]` to begin with?

Comment: Ya there's a reason: the code above is a small slice of a much longer code, and for that, I needed to have ArrayLists.

Comment: Ah okay, that makes more sense. In that case, it might help to break down exactly what you're trying to do. It sounds like you want to be doing something for each item in your list, but you're trying to pass the list directly instead of actually looping through each element.

Comment: Is that why this question is being voted down?

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me.

Comment: btw, you should investigate before asking a question, this is a really easy question and you could google this and resolve the issue by your own, otherwise you won't really learn how to do it, and that's why you are getting downvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to split each String in list1 on "," and attempt to parse each String that gets split out:

```
    ArrayList<Double[]> results = Lists.newArrayList();
    for( String s : list1 ) {
        String[] splitStrings = s.split(",");
        Double[] doublesForCurrentString = new Double[splitStrings.length];
        for(int i=0; i<splitStrings.length; i++){
            try {
                doublesForCurrentString[i] = Double.valueOf(splitStrings[i]);
            } catch( NumberFormatException ex ) {
                // No action.
            }
        }
        results.add(doublesForCurrentString);
    }
    Double[][] doubleArray = (Double[][])results.toArray();
```

Crucial points:

- **EDIT**:  As @Tim Herold points out, you're probably better of performance-wise avoiding attempting to parse content you know to be non-numeric.  In this case, I'd still split first and then just put in code that prevents  you from attempting to parseDouble() on the first split String in each line, rather than trying to do String replacement before the split; that will be faster (and if we're not concerned about performance, then try/catch is perfectly fine and more readable).  **ORIGINAL**: You need a try/catch when you try to parse the doubles, in case there's any invalid input.  Bonus: you don't need to remove the non-numeric text now, you can just let this try/catch handle it.
- Your strings have **two** doubles in each of them.  You're not going to be able to just strip the text at the beginning and then parse the rest, because it's not going to be a valid double.
- ArrayLists are generally easier to use; I'd opt for returning `ArrayList<Double>` (or `ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>`) over `Double[]` or `Double[][]` any day of the week.  There are certainly situations where I'd do differently, but yours doesn't sound like one of them to me.

Comment: I wouldn't recommad to use `try{}catch(){}` as programmlogic, you should extract the non-double chars

Comment: I am getting a "cannot find symbol" error under "Lists". I imported java.lang.Object, so I'm not sure what's wrong. Any thoughts?

Comment: [Lists](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html) is part of [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), but it's just a helper method to make it easier to use java.util.collections.  You can replace that call with new ArrayList<Double[]> and be just fine.

Comment: @Tim Herold: Your point is well taken.  In this case, with a well-known format where you can exclude the non-double chars without running a regex (e.g. by not trying to parse the first String from the `split()`), yeah, it's probably worth doing that.  But if the frequency of non-double chars were very low, I'd use a try-catch instead of running a regex on every line just for the occasional ones that were non-numeric.

Answer (score 1):

Loop throug the Array:

```
foreach String[]
    double[counter] = parseToDouble(String[counter])
```

**EDIT:**
Java:

```
   String[] str1 = list1.toArray(str1);
   double[] dou1 = new double[str1.length]
   for(int counter = 0; counter < str1.length;counter++)
      dou1[counter] = Double.parseDouble(str1[counter].replaceAll("RSP_\\d+",""));
```

Comment: parse to Double probably should include the replace all :D

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean "for each String[]" ? Are you adding to what I have or replacing something? Thanks

Comment: "str1.size()" is not found in either instance. I think it's because str1 is a string[] not a string

Comment: sorry, .size() = .length

Comment: "str1 might not have been initialized" error in the first line. Perhaps I need to need declare it before I make it into an array?

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
 String[] str1 = new String[list1.size()];
 str1 = list1.toArray(str1);
 double[] doubleArray = new double[str1.length]
 int i=0;
 for(String s:str1){
    doubleArray[i] = Double.valueOf(s.trim());
    i++;
 }
```

Comment: This leads to a "number format exception" error for the input string. That's why I need to remove the RSP d+ expression from the input

Comment: Removing the stuff from the beginning of the string isn't enough to make it correct input.  ",1.11,1.22" is still not a valid double.  Which of those two numbers that are separated by commas are you actually trying to parse?  Then build a regex that gets just that.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the work.

```
double[] doubles = new double[array1.length];
for(int i=0; i<array1.length; i++){
   doubles[i] = Double.valueOf(array1[i])
}
```

Thanks SmartLemon for the edit, you could do this too instead of using a `String[]`:

```
double[] doubles = new double[list1.size()];
for(int i=0; i<list1.size(); i++){
   doubles[i] = Double.valueOf(list1.get(i).replace("RSP_\\d+",""));
}
```

EDIT: So yes, you need a delimiter:

```
double[] doubles = new double[array1.length*2]; //multiply by 2 because you really have 8 numbers not 4
String [] array2 = null;

for(String string: array1) { 
    array2 = string.split(",");
    for(int i=0; i<array2.length; i++){
        doubles[i] = Double.valueOf(array2[i]);
    }
}
```

this should do the work for sure.

Comment: i don't know why you need to pass from `ArrayList<String>` to `String[]` but if there is an special case then just use first snippet of code, where `array1` is a `String[]`

Comment: For the second "snippet", I'm getting a "Format Number Exception" for the input string.

Comment: Also, I think "new doubles" should be "new double"

Comment: well, that depends on your String, if you are getting a NumberFormatException it indicates that your String is not exactly a pure number String, try printing the String "numbers" before the parsing.

Comment: are you sure that regex it's actually returning a valid double number? i see 2 possibles delimitators there a "." or a "," i think your regex is returning this at the first replace ",1.11,1.22", of course it will throw a NumberFormatException.

Answer (score -1):

I would do this:

- make array
- convert to string

then this code

```java
for (String s: list1) {
    boolean obtained = false;
    double tempD;

    try {
        tempD = Double.parseDouble(s); 
        obtained = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (obtained) {
        list2.add(tempD);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code neatly (and I think you're also missing a `}`)

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this site. I was having difficulties getting the parser here to recognize it as code each time I would press enter.

Comment: It looks like `list1` is the original `String[]` and `list2` is the `Double[]` where he's storing parsed results