# Floating decimal error while converting string array to double array

Tags: java, arrays, string, double

When I try to convert a string array to a double array, I keep getting a "floatingdecimal.readjavaformatstring" error. Note that the string array looks something like this:  (but it goes on for much longer)

```
7.641844673,7.643565703,7.319638605,7.42366145,7.419292812,7.388869123,7.53670762,7.749329445,7.625242329,7.322164604,7.315094508,7.403445746,7.890969983,7.544904537,7.677043042,7.477693567,7.527992118,7.415580204,7.417685294,7.393078839
```

And my conversion looks like this:  (where str1 is a String[] )

```
double[] array1 = new double[str1.length];
for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) 
{
array1[i] = Double.parseDouble(str1[i]);
}
```

I'm pretty sure that the conversion is correct, but there's something in my string that's amiss, such as an extra comma or something. Do you have any suggestions as to how I can fix my string? Or do you think I should do my conversion differently?

Thanks a lot,

KJM

Comment: Please show the error message in its entirety.

Comment: Just confirm to us you're splitting that String of floats correctly, what's the code you use to go from `String` to `String[]`?

Comment: @morgano: I don't see where he mentions "splitting" a String, but I agree if he is in fact splitting and not taking care of white space properly, he will run into trouble.

Comment: Presumably this is a follow-up from his question earlier in the day.

Comment: @DennisMeng: Thanks for the heads up. It's frustrating when we're forced to guess what's really going on behind the scenes. To the original poster, consider posting all the information needed to allow us to understand and answer the question. Your previous question was down-voted for the very same reason. Someone gave you an answer, but if your questions were more complete, you'd have a complete answer and wouldn't have to ask this follow-up question. Please have a look at: [The Perfect Question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx)

Comment: Link to said question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18135043/convert-string-with-text-to-double

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: I put in all the information I thought was relevant in both posts, but this question came up as a small part of a much larger code, and I'm not going to provide all of it. I asked a follow up because NONE of the answers I got in the other post were error-free. So, I tried to make the question a little simpler and more exact here. I'm not sure what else I can do.

Comment: @kjm: please read the link that I've supplied in my last comment above this one. It will tell you what we need to know that will help us answer questions and not have to guess or give advice that doesn't work or help. The link has helped me a great deal and I'm sure will help you too.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str1 = "7.641844673,7.643565703,7.319638605,7.42366145,7.419292812,7.388869123,7.53670762,7.749329445,7.625242329,7.322164604,7.315094508,7.403445746,7.890969983,7.544904537,7.677043042,7.477693567,7.527992118,7.415580204,7.417685294,7.393078839";
        String[] split = str1.split(",");
        double[] doublearray = new double[split.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
            doublearray[i] = Double.parseDouble(split[i]);

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < doublearray.length; i++) {
            System.err.println(doublearray[i]);
        }
    }
```

try this , it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you did not use `String[] str1 = givenString.split(",");`